# A task to run when a running DAG is stopped/killed

Tags: airflow

Any idea there is any hook to run a task when DAG is stopped from the airflow UI?

Answer (score 0):

Something different than the callbacks offered on a task? Theres the on success callback, on failure callback, and on retry callback.